# Calling one constructor from another in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I am displaying one window now and when i will press some key i should be able to move to different window. How to do it in QT?
Actually i am having mainwindow class which i am calling from main class. And then through that mainwindow class i want to call other class lets say window2.

Main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv);
    mywindow window;
    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

mywindow.cpp

```
mywindow::mywindow(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
//What should we used here to call 2nd constructor window2
       window2 obj;
       obj.show();
       this.hide();
}
```

window2.cpp

```
window2::window2(QWidget *parent)
{

}
```

Now i have used `hide()` or `show()`. But now it is not working properly and window2 is not able to display.

Comment: Since you are creating `window2` on the stack it will be destroyed as soon as you leave your constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should created window2 in heap and use window1 as the parent, so that window2 exists as long as the parent exists and destroyed by the parent when the parent itself gets destroyed.

```
 mywindow::mywindow(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{

   window2* obj=new window2(this);
   obj->show();
   this->hide(); // don't use '.' operator for pointer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Second window is put on stack

```
   window2 obj;
```

It is properly created and displayed but you have no chance to see it as the window is gone as soon as you encounter enclosing brace of the scope in which it was created - the body of mywindow constructor.

```
mywindow::mywindow(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
       window2 obj;      // obj window is created on stack
       obj.show();
       this.hide();
}                        // obj window dies
```

You should instead create new window on a free store.